# SQL Server concatenation separated by comma only when column is not null

Tags: sql-server, string, string-concatenation

I have the following SQL statement:

```
@All = COALESCE(NULLIF(@Asc1, '') + ',', '') +
        OALESCE(NULLIF(@Asc2, '') + ',', '') +
        OALESCE(NULLIF(@Asc3, '') + ',', '');
```

This will insert a comma at the end even if any of the variables (`@Asc1`, `@Asc2`, `@Asc3`) have NULL or empty values.

For example:

- if `@Asc1 = 1234` and `@Asc2 = 3456` and `@Asc3 = ''`, then `@All` will end up being `1234,3456,`

I would like `@All` to be `1234,3456`

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

using `stuff()` to remove the first comma and reversing the comma concatenation:

```
set @all = stuff(
    coalesce(','+nullif(@Asc1, ''), '')
  + coalesce(','+nullif(@Asc2, ''), '')
  + coalesce(','+nullif(@Asc3, ''), '')
  ,1,1,'');
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/UNDS90887

returns: `1234,3456`

Comment: Yeah, this deserves to be accepted, as I did not handle the case when the first value(s) is/are NULL.

Comment: @slartidan if all values are null, then all will be set to null.

Comment: @StephenOberauer So depending on the use case, it might be a good idea to wrap the whole expression in an additional `COALESCE(..., '')` statement.

Answer (score 6):

I know this post is already answered and is correct. But would like to post the below answer because from SQL Server 2017 onwards, this is too easy and someoen might find this helpful in future.

```
SELECT @all = CONCAT_WS(',',@Asc1,@Asc2,@Asc3)
```